# Outline border bottom only

Tags: html, css, border, outline

I'd like to create a bottom outline border when the cursor is over an image and I don't know how to do this. I'd like to use this kind of inner border because I don't want to have layout problems with a traditional border-bottom.

Here's my current code, with outline margins everywhere:

```css
.img-lightbox-small {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 1px;
}

a img.img-lightbox-small:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  outline: 3px solid #4bb6f5;
  outline-offset: -3px;
}
```

Comment: Outline does not allow one side to have it only.

Comment: You could do something like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/8XjM5/)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To get around the problem you can use `border-bottom`, with it set `margin-bottom: -1px` (the size of the border). This will stop it from moving the content below.

**HTML:**

```
<div></div>
test
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
}
div:hover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/8XjM5/)

Comment: I'm opened to any other solution. What do you mean by not pretty?

Comment: How do you color the border? Mine always shows black

Comment: @JoePhillips `border-color: red;` just normal CSS.

Answer (score 4):

`outline` is not like the border property. you have all sides, or none.
you'd better use the border property mixed with `box-sizing:border-box` which overwrites the box-model, so that your layout doesnt "move".

http://jsfiddle.net/8XjM5/1/

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
div:hover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;

}
```

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't go for this as it is using `CSS3`.

Comment: I tried this too, but when I apply it my image is moving (size is reducing when a:hover) which is not the case with the other code... See http://jsfiddle.net/8XjM5/4/ (Sorry I didn't know how to use this web site I think I deleted your code *Newbie*)

Comment: img is an inline element , that property only applies to block elements. anyway, even if it is a css3 feature it's widely supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing